# Скрыть/показать input Javascript

Tags: javascript, input

Как сделать на JS, чтобы при нажатии на `input` "Два", `input` "*Скат набок*" в блоке *Тип кровли* был **скрыт**, а при нажатии `input` "Один" **показан** и `input` "*Скат назад*" был отмечен *checked*  ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<form action="" name="theform">
  <div>Конструктор гаража
    <div>
      <p>Количество автомобилей</p>
      <input type="radio" checked id="vor1" name="number" value="one"> Один
      <input type="radio" id="vor2" name="number" value="two"> Два
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Тип кровли</p>
      <input type="radio" checked id="crovl1" name="skat" value="skatBack"> Скат назад
      <input type="radio" id="crovl2" name="skat" value ="twoSkat"> Двускатная
      <input type="radio" id="crovl3" name="skat" value="skatLeft"> Скат набок
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Приложи свой Html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#vor1, #vor2").forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (this.id == 'vor2' && this.checked) {
      if (document.getElementById("crovl3")) {
        document.getElementById("crovl3").parentElement.remove();
      }
      document.getElementById("crovl1").checked = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="" name="theform">
  <div>Конструктор гаража
    <div>
      <p>Количество автомобилей</p>
      <input type="radio" checked id="vor1" name="number" value="one"> Один
      <input type="radio" id="vor2" name="number" value="two"> Два
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Тип кровли</p>
      <input type="radio" checked id="crovl1" name="skat" value="skatBack"> Скат назад
      <label><input type="radio" id="crovl3" name="skat" value="skatLeft"> Скат набок</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

*Обратите внимание, что для корректного удаления текста рядом с `input#crovl3`, для него был добавлен `label`.*

---

**UPD** - отображение и скрытие `input#crovl3` "Скат набок" без удаления

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#vor1, #vor2").forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (document.getElementById("vor1").checked) {
      document.getElementById("crovl3").parentElement.style.display = 'inline-block';
    } else if (document.getElementById("vor2").checked) {
      document.getElementById("crovl3").parentElement.style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("crovl1").checked = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="" name="theform">
  <div>Конструктор гаража
    <div>
      <p>Количество автомобилей</p>
      <input type="radio" checked id="vor1" name="number" value="one"> Один
      <input type="radio" id="vor2" name="number" value="two"> Два
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Тип кровли</p>
      <input type="radio" checked id="crovl1" name="skat" value="skatBack"> Скат назад
      <label><input type="radio" id="crovl3" name="skat" value="skatLeft"> Скат набок</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. Но еще такое, я не указал, думал будет понятно, но видимо не понятно. При щелчке на Один, инпут нижний должен опять показываться

Comment: Разобрался вроде сам. Но удаление не подходит как метод, потому что я вешаю на эти инпуты изменение картинки. А если удалять и потом возвращать, то другая функция не успевает видеть что удаленный инпут вернулся. Это вот еще одна проблема))

Comment: @RedLionHeart добавил в ответ вариант со скрытием `input` без его удаления

Answer (score 0):

Данное решение использует Jquery. Ниже решение вашей задачи:

```js
$('#vor1').on('click',function(){
    $('#crovl3').parent().fadeIn(500);
    $('#vor2').prop('checked',false);
    $('#crovl1').prop('checked',false);
});
$('#vor2').on('click',function(){
    $('#crovl3').parent().fadeOut(500);
    $('#vor1, #crovl2, #crovl3').prop('checked',false);
    $('#crovl1').prop('checked',true);
});
$('#crovl1, #crovl2, #crovl3').on('change',function(){
    $('#crovl1, #crovl2, #crovl3').prop('checked',false);
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="theform">
  <div>Конструктор гаража
    <div>
      <p>Количество автомобилей</p>
      <label for="vor1">
          <input type="radio" id="vor1" name="number-1" value="one" checked>Один
      </label>
      <label for="vor2">
           <input type="radio" id="vor2" name="number-2" value="two">Два
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Тип кровли</p>
      <label for="crovl1">
           <input type="radio" id="crovl1" name="skat-1" value="skatBack" checked>Скат назад
      </label>
      <label for="crovl2">
          <input type="radio" id="crovl2" name="skat-2" value ="twoSkat">Двускатная
      </label>
      <label for="crovl3">
           <input type="radio" id="crovl3" name="skat-3" value="skatLeft">Скат набок
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Очень криво работает. Может в этом виноват я, что не указал. При перещелкивании обратно на 'Один' должно опять показывать еще один инпут снизу. И при удалении в данный момент одновременно выбраны и 'Один' и 'Два'

Comment: @RedLionHeart Вот решение вашей задачи. Что конкретно работает криво?

Comment: вы уже изменили. Смотрите, если нажать на Два, а затем на Двускатная, то получается что выбраны два инпута снизу.

Comment: @RedLionHeart сейчас подправлю)

Comment: @RedLionHeart готово